# Jest how to change global variable to cover all branches

Tags: javascript, jestjs, frontend

[image: 1]

```
// target.js
const urlPrefix = IS_TEST_ENV || _DEV_ ? 'https://xxx/cms/media/' : 'https://zzz/cms/media/';

const formatImageSizeUrl = (url, size) => {
  if (!/\d+x\d+/.test(size)) {
    return url;
  }
  if (url.startsWith(urlPrefix)) {
    return `${url}?d=${size}`;
  }
  return url;
};
...

// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
 globals: {
  IS_TEST_ENV: true,
  _DEV_: true
 }
}
```

how to change IS_TEST_ENV and *DEV* into **false** temporarily.so can cover all branches

Comment: Those env vars are used at module import time, which makes it more difficult. You could just _not_ test that branch, it's pretty trivial, or consider extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion on this is that your code has some logic that needs mocking, but that logic is implicit and not currently mockable. I would refactor the code as follows:

```js
// settings.js
// Check whether we are on a production environment or not
export const isProd = () => !(IS_TEST_ENV || _DEV_)

// target.js
// Reversed order of URLs as the boolean expression returns true if we are in production
const urlPrefix = isProd() ? 'https://zzz/cms/media/' : 'https://xxx/cms/media/';

// target.test.js
// Mock out isProd() to return true, as by default it will be false
jest.mock('../settings', () => {
  isProd: () => true
})

// Run test to ensure we are getting the right URL
```

The upside to this approach is that you have a single canonical source of whether you're in production or not, which is useful if you wind up needing to make that check in multiple places. You also only need to mock out or update one method if you want to change this behaviour in the future.